# Invariant Violation: App (…):Nothing was returned from render.This usually means a return statement is missing.Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, react-native, switch-statement, styles, render

```
Import React, { useReducer } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import ColorCounter from '../components/ColorCounter'

Const Color_Increament = 15;
const reducer = (state, action) => {   switch (action.ColortoChange) {
     case 'red':
     return ({ ...state, red: state.red + action.amount });
     case 'green':
     return ({ ...state, green: state.green + action.amount });
     case 'blue':
     return ({ ...state, blue: state.blue + action.amount });
     default:
     return state;
    }
}
const SquareScreen = () => {

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer,
    ({ red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 }));
const { red, green, blue } = state;

const setColor = (color, change) => {

    return (
        <View>

            <ColorCounter
                onIncrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'red', amount: (Color_Increament) })}
                onDecrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'red', amount: (-1 * Color_Increament) })}

                color="Red" />

            <ColorCounter
                onIncrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'green', amount: (Color_Increament) })}
                onDecrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'green', amount: (-1 * Color_Increament) })}

                color="Green" />

            <ColorCounter
                onIncrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'blue', amount: (Color_Increament) })}
                onDecrease={() => dispatch(
                    { ColortoChange: 'blue', amount: (-1 * Color_Increament) })}

                color="Blue" />

            <View
                style={{
                    height: 150, width: 150,
                    backgroundColor:
                        `rgb(${state.red},${state.green},${state.blue})`
                }}
            />

        </View>
    )
};
}

Const styles = StyleSheet.create ({});

Export default SquareScreen;
```

Comment: Please provide additional details. What do you want to achieve? What is your problem? Not just piece of code.

Comment: Grammar; layout.